# excel incrementation by consecutive numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, increment

I have a form, thanks to user JamTay317, That lists data depending on folder number (bold number in form). I need to copy it for all 1500 folders (about 400 pages)
Form is divided  on 4 labels on a page for easier printing

[form overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ygY.jpg)

Form get it's folder number (nr teczki) from list with all folders from another sheet called "lista teczek":

[list of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeHIA.jpg)

For first 4 folder numbers I use formula:

```
A2='lista teczek'!A1
J2='lista teczek'!A2
A21='lista teczek'!A3
J21='lista teczek'!A4
```

When I copy whole page underneath it increments by 36 (number of rows between)

```
A38='lista teczek'!A37
J38='lista teczek'!A38
A57='lista teczek'!A39
J38='lista teczek'!A40
```

Instead of A5, A6, etc.

Is there any way to override excel's incrementation to force it to use consecutive numbers? Or at least formula which will make it easier to follow folders list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would use offset() to get the correct position

```
=A2=OFFSET('lista teczek'!$A$1;ROW(A1)-INT(ROW(A1)/36)*36+4*INT(ROW(A1)/36)-1;0)
```

So this will offset from A1 in the list sheet.
Below are row numbers a resultant lookup row numbers
Note the formula I used in the offset has an extra "-1" as this is an OFFSET so to get 1 from 1 we need to offset by 0

```
    1   1
    2   2
    3   3
    4   4
    37  5
    38  6
    39  7
    40  8
    73  9
    74  10
    75  11
    76  12
    109 13
    110 14
    111 15
    112 16
    145 17
    146 18
    147 19
```

----LOGIC--- (edit)

So the idea is that you work out the occurrence you are on. Int(row()/36) gives us this. For example

```
int(1/36)=0 
Int(363/36)=10
```

First part gives us the offset from the start of the occurrence

```
3-int(3/36)*36=3 
378-Int(363/36)*36=3
```

Second part give the total of the previous occurrence

```
4*int(3/36)=0 
4*Int(363/36)*36=40
```

So you need to change the 36 to the gap between the occurrences and the 4 to the length of occurrences Not sure if that helps to explain

Comment: Ok it works, but how should I copy it from first cell to another cells?

Comment: I can only make it work for first row A2 and J2, next row A21 and J21 is using data from 'lista teczek'!A22 and A23 instead of A3 and A4
On the other hand next row uses it properly showing 5th and 6th value

Comment: Also if could you tell me syntax of this formula, why divide by 36, then multiply by it, why +4?

Comment: So the idea is that you work out the occurrence you are on.

Int(row()/36) gives us this. For example 
int(1/36)=0
Int(363/36)=10

First part gives us the offset from the start of the occurrence
3-int(3/36)*36=3
378-Int(363/36)*36=3

Second part give the total of the previous occurrence
4*int(3/36)=0
4*Int(363/36)*36=40

So you need to change the 36 to the gap between the occurrences and the 4 to the length of occurrences

Not sure if that helps to explain

Comment: thanks for replay, however, don't know why this formula wasn't working for second row, so I found a rather simple answer.
For 'list teczek I added column if incrementing numbers
And so on, then added a number in same row as formula but different column and changed formula to 
' =VLOOKUP(A2;'lista teczek'!$A:$B;2;0) '
Now it perfectly increment by 4 as it should, even for 400 pages